# WPF XAML : Load items to combobox in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid source which has CabinetName as property. I want the selected item to be this Cabinet name and the combobox dropdown to be filled from a new List FCabinetNames. I write this combobox template into my wpf datagrid to implement this functionality.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cabinet">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding CabinetName}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FCabinetNames}"></ComboBox>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now the selected item is showing up correctly so TextBlock Text part is fine. But the item source is not loaded fine.

I have this snippet for the item source.

```
public class FCabinetNames:List<string>

{
    BusinessLogic admintasks = new BusinessLogic();
    public FCabinetNames()
    {
        try
        {
            List<CabinetData> cab1 = admintasks.CabinetDataforGrid();
            List<string> fcabinetname = new List<string>();
            foreach (var c1 in cab1)
            {
                this.Add(c1.CabinetName);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should even get binding error in output window saying that _string does not support IEnumberble_ as you set `ItemsSource` to "FCabinetNames" string in this line: `ItemsSource="FCabinetNames"`. I think you wanted to use binding instead

Comment: Infact i used ItemsSource="{Binding FCabinetNames}" when i got blank itemsource.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is that `CabinetName` is not in the same view model class as `FCabinetNames`. Is that correct?

Comment: @dkozi : I am not using MVVM but no they are not on the same file. CabinetName is on a class that gets the entire cabinet data. But like i said FCabinetNames is a string list i use just as combobox source.

Comment: But where is `FCabinetNames` declared? Is it another property in the class where your declared `CabinetName` or somewhere else?

Comment: It is infact a public property

Comment: Made some progress.But item source is not loaded. I have pasted the entire code. So please guide